# Find Clicked UIImageview From UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I attached events to my UIImageViews with UITapGestureRecognizer

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let cupPicture1Tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
    cupPicture1.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cupPicture1.addGestureRecognizer(cupPicture1Tap)
    let cupPicture2Tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
    cupPicture2.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cupPicture2.addGestureRecognizer(cupPicture2Tap)
    let cupPicture3Tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
    cupPicture3.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cupPicture3.addGestureRecognizer(cupPicture3Tap)
  }

  func cupImageTapped(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var clickedImageView: UIImageView = recognizer.view

    let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self;
    myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    myPickerController.allowsEditing = true
    self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

But i can't access which UIImageView clicked at cupImageTapped function. I am getting: "Cannot convert value of type 'UIView?' to specified type 'UIImageView'"

Comment: you are not attched the tap gesture method , you were attatched the pangesture method , plz update your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var MyImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // create tap gesture recognizer
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapGesture:")

    // add it to the image view;
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    // make sure imageView can be interacted with by user
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true        
}

func tapGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // if the tapped view is a UIImageView then set it to imageview
    if let imageView = gesture.view as? UIImageView {  // if you subclass UIImageView, then change "UIImageView" to your subclass
        // change the image on the MyImageView
        MyImageView.image = imageView.image
        // if you subclass UIImageView, then you could get the filename here.
    }
}
```

This will work

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast it to `UIImageView`

```
if var clickedImageView = recognizer.view as? UIImageView{
     //Use clickedImageView here
}
```